# Transparent background toolbar - how to give it attention, but not too much

Tags: ipad, toolbar

I am building an ipad application.
In my application I show images.
I've got a toolbar that contains basic abilities like sharing, shopping etc.

I want my toolbar to be an anchor point throughout the application, as users can swipe to different page, yet the toolbar remains the same.

My problem is how to set the right ratio between not making my toolbar too significant and yet keeping it visible and accessible.

This is my current solution (see attached image), though I feel as though it currently gives a sparse feeling, with no real anchor point.

Do you have any suggestions? How should I tackle this issue?

[image: Our toolbar]

Comment: Why are you not using the [standard Tab Bar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: Because I don't like the way it looks. It's too standard and it doesn't achieve what I am trying to get

Answer (score 4):

Use a semi transparant overlay, similar to a modal screen. See attached.
Though you'll probably need to modify the layout...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer use 0 transparancy at beginning, on touch you can make it visible, probably with an animation like slide down from top , this way you can show ur product(images) completely without any hindrance also by animating , you are catching the attention of the user to know that they have something to play with!! :)